# htaccess and htpasswd?

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

My first time using htaccess to ask for a user password.
on my server

.htpasswd file lies in my root directory of my server.

.htaccess file lies in folder folder "uploads" (which lies in the root dir)

i used …

```
    <?php
    echo dirname(__FILE__);
    ?>
```

to get the full server path to my root dir.

my .htaccess file in my "uploads" folder looks like this now:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Uploads to my website"
AuthUserFile /home/.sites/74/site484/web .htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

and my .htpasswd file in the root looks like this:

```
admin:$apr4$CxS3O/..$vJcWNd6tlUwg6PAn.6cpA1
```

now when i browser to mydomain.com/uploads i get:

**Internal Server Error**
*The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.*

what am i doing wrong here?

thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like there's a space instead of a slash between the directory and file name in the AuthUserFile line.

Comment: jesus, you're right! man, sry for the question. now it's working!

Comment: @mathiregister: Accept the answer if its working now. Accepting the answer is the best way to thank anyone on SO.