# Testdomain indexed by Google. How to fix this?

Tags: seo, http-status-code-301

During development we use a domain on a testserver. When development is complete we "push" our code to the livedomain (on liveserver). Development only occurs on testdomain.

During development we added Google Analytics to our code. Now Google indexed our developmentdomain and shows both the live and testdomain in the searchresults.
We only want our livedomain in Google Searchresults.

I read some documentation about 301-redirects. But is it the best way to fix this problem?

Developmentdomain: http://developer.example.com:81 (on testserver)
Live-domain: http://www.example.com (on liveserver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google respects robots.txt see: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449

You can add a robots.txt in the root of your domain with the content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

However, this will not solve your problem immediately, Google Bot will need to visit your site again.

Also, have a look at this: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164734

Comment: By only adding the robot.txt file to the testdomain the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove your test domain you have to hide this domain for access from world.

You can set in apache, ngix, tomcat or something else, that you can access this domain from specific IP - that is normally done when you want to show site to your client or want to test site...

Then you will have to wait about one month, when google will see, that there is no such domain or websites and will remove it from google index.

Comment: For testing it will be a lot of work to add each IP of the testusers to allow access. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Google Webmasters](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) to request a URL removal (Site Configuration > Crawler Access) to speed up removal of the url from the index. You can also check [this](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164734&from=156412&rd=1) for more detail.

301 redirect will not fix anything for you since I suppose you will still need access to that domain but only to the development group. You can deny/allow access from specific IPs to that subdomain.

Comment: I still need access to that domain for the development group. We also use groups of people to test our application. So allowing each tester would be a lot of work.

Comment: You may want to protect the whole directory with a htpasswd. Here is more detail [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655771/htaccess-and-htpasswd).